# Auto format phone number in JavaScript (not JQuery)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I found the following code for formatting the phone number in JavaScript on [**this post from stack overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471788/formatting-the-phone-number-for-multiple-asptextbox-in-javascript) but it is not in U.S standard format and I want the space after closing ')'

i.e. The following code gave me output **(123)456-7890** but I want **(123) 456-7890**, want to include space after the closing ')'. I tried it but no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Phone validation
    var zChar = new Array(' ', '(', ')', '-', '.');
    var maxphonelength = 13;
    var phonevalue1;
    var phonevalue2;
    var cursorposition;

    function ParseForNumber1(object) {
        phonevalue1 = ParseChar(object.value, zChar);
    }
    function ParseForNumber2(object) {
        phonevalue2 = ParseChar(object.value, zChar);
    }

    function backspacerUP(object, e) {
        if (e) {
            e = e
        } else {
            e = window.event
        }
        if (e.which) {
            var keycode = e.which
        } else {
            var keycode = e.keyCode
        }

        ParseForNumber1(object)

        if (keycode >= 48) {
            ValidatePhone(object)
        }
    }

    function backspacerDOWN(object, e) {
        if (e) {
            e = e
        } else {
            e = window.event
        }
        if (e.which) {
            var keycode = e.which
        } else {
            var keycode = e.keyCode
        }
        ParseForNumber2(object)
    }

    function GetCursorPosition() {

        var t1 = phonevalue1;
        var t2 = phonevalue2;
        var bool = false
        for (i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
            if (t1.substring(i, 1) != t2.substring(i, 1)) {
                if (!bool) {
                    cursorposition = i
                    bool = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function ValidatePhone(object) {

        var p = phonevalue1

        p = p.replace(/[^\d]*/gi, "")

        if (p.length < 3) {
            object.value = p
        } else if (p.length == 3) {
            pp = p;
            d4 = p.indexOf('(')
            d5 = p.indexOf(')')
            if (d4 == -1) {
                pp = "(" + pp;
            }
            if (d5 == -1) {
                pp = pp + ")";
            }
            object.value = pp;
        } else if (p.length > 3 && p.length < 7) {
            p = "(" + p;
            l30 = p.length;
            p30 = p.substring(0, 4);
            p30 = p30 + ")"

            p31 = p.substring(4, l30);
            pp = p30 + p31;

            object.value = pp;

        } else if (p.length >= 7) {
            p = "(" + p;
            l30 = p.length;
            p30 = p.substring(0, 4);
            p30 = p30 + ")"

            p31 = p.substring(4, l30);
            pp = p30 + p31;

            l40 = pp.length;
            p40 = pp.substring(0, 8);
            p40 = p40 + "-"

            p41 = pp.substring(8, l40);
            ppp = p40 + p41;

            object.value = ppp.substring(0, maxphonelength);
        }

        GetCursorPosition()

        if (cursorposition >= 0) {
            if (cursorposition == 0) {
                cursorposition = 2
            } else if (cursorposition <= 2) {
                cursorposition = cursorposition + 1
            } else if (cursorposition <= 5) {
                cursorposition = cursorposition + 2
            } else if (cursorposition == 6) {
                cursorposition = cursorposition + 2
            } else if (cursorposition == 7) {
                cursorposition = cursorposition + 4
                e1 = object.value.indexOf(')')
                e2 = object.value.indexOf('-')
                if (e1 > -1 && e2 > -1) {
                    if (e2 - e1 == 4) {
                        cursorposition = cursorposition - 1
                    }
                }
            } else if (cursorposition < 11) {
                cursorposition = cursorposition + 3
            } else if (cursorposition == 11) {
                cursorposition = cursorposition + 1
            } else if (cursorposition >= 12) {
                cursorposition = cursorposition
            }

            var txtRange = object.createTextRange();
            txtRange.moveStart("character", cursorposition);
            txtRange.moveEnd("character", cursorposition - object.value.length);
            txtRange.select();
        }

    }

    function ParseChar(sStr, sChar) {
        if (sChar.length == null) {
            zChar = new Array(sChar);
        }
        else zChar = sChar;

        for (i = 0; i < zChar.length; i++) {
            sNewStr = "";

            var iStart = 0;
            var iEnd = sStr.indexOf(sChar[i]);

            while (iEnd != -1) {
                sNewStr += sStr.substring(iStart, iEnd);
                iStart = iEnd + 1;
                iEnd = sStr.indexOf(sChar[i], iStart);
            }
            sNewStr += sStr.substring(sStr.lastIndexOf(sChar[i]) + 1, sStr.length);

            sStr = sNewStr;
        }

        return sNewStr;
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to use this function in multiple phone textboxes and all those are in `asp:Textbox`.

Comment: Array(' ', '(', ') ', '-', '.');

Comment: That code seems really complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a phone number with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760070/how-to-format-a-phone-number-with-jquery)

Comment: Your code is very complicated and I don't quite get understand what you really want. Assuming to got a string of number like `var phone = "1234567890"` or `var phone = "123-456-7890"` and you want it to be formatted as `(ddd) ddd-dddd` this would work `phone.replace(/\D/g,"").replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3")` It will first strip all non digit, then replace the 10 digit string number with your preferred format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert the space after the closing braces ')' use the following trick:

```
function markSpace(field) {
        if (field.value.includes(")")) {
            field.value = field.value.split(')').join(') ');
        }
        if (field.value.includes(") ")) {
            field.value = field.value.replace(/  +/g, ' ');

        }
    }
```

and call the above function as `onblur="markSpace(this);"`

Or, this will be short and working answer for your problem

`JavaScript` code:

```
 window.addFormat = function addFormat(f) {
        var r = /(\D+)/g,
            npa = '',
            nxx = '',
            last4 = '';
        f.value = f.value.replace(r, '');
        npa = f.value.substr(0, 3);
        nxx = f.value.substr(3, 3);
        last4 = f.value.substr(6, 4);
        f.value = '(' + npa + ') ' + nxx + '-' + last4;
    }
```

and `asp:Textbox` as

```
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="14" 
             runat="server" 
             ID="txtPhone"  
             placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" 
             onKeyup='addFormat(this)'/>
```

Reference: [This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093187/javascript-dashes-in-phone-number)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the code is overly complicated. You should provide a number only input ( and may + too), and then show the result below the input, so the user sees what it is formatted to. Html:

```
<input type="number" id="phone">
<p id="showphone">enter a number above</p>
```

And the js:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
  var showphone = document.getElementById("showphone");

 phone.oninput = function(){
  var result = phone.value.split("");
  result.splice(0,0,"(")
  result.splice(4,0,") ")
  result.splice(8,0," - ");

  showphone.textContent = result.join("");
 };
});
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/cunubidilo/edit?output)

If you want to display these formattings just if neccessary, do:

```
if(result.length > 3 ) result.splice(4,0,"(")
```

Comment: I am using the above code in asp:Textbox. Is your solution will work for asp control??

Comment: Though I deleted the phone number the label still shows "() - " how do you delete that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to do that

```
function formatPhone(__phone){      
    var pt = /[\(\)\- ]+/gi
    __phone = __phone.replace(pt, '');
    __phone = '('+__phone.substr(0,3)+') '+__phone.substr(2,3)+'-'+__phone.substr(6,4);
    return __phone;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking me why I named the variable holding a phone number in string "__phone" ?????????

Comment: Yes. why not phone?? the op may wants to edit the code, the __ makes it more hard

Comment: Oh well I like to add __ in front of params so it makes it clear in my code what is passed.

Comment: its rather usual to use underscores for unused parameters and private proerties / methods. And im not shure how it should help you coding if you now that   its a parameter...

Answer (score 0):

You may have some clues out of here.

```
let testNumber = "(123-12)3-1234";

function formatPhoneNumber(num) {
  const number = num.match(/\d/g, "");
  const joinedNumber = number.join("");
  console.log(joinedNumber);
  const regex = /^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/;
  const final = joinedNumber.replace(regex, "($1)$2-$3");
  return final;
  console.log(final);
}
formatPhoneNumber(testNumber);
// print on console: (123)123-1234
```

I put `console.log`s so that you can visualize what is going on.
0. the format of `testNumber` doesn't matter, but it needs to be 10 digits (because of `const regex`) 
1. `const number` returns an array with each number as an element.
2. `const joinedNumber` returns a number that all elements are attached (1231231234)
3. `const regex` makes parts so that you can control later with replace// () = parts, so as you can see there are 3 parts. You can change `regex` format as you want to format
4. finally, `joinedNumber.replace(regex, "($1)$2-$3)` will return (123)123-1234 
5. you can change `"($1)$2-$3` part to make a format whatever you want.

Hope you find it helpful.